# ERROR: can not find control file (.bcf)!

Tags: bibliographies

When I compile my paper with Biber mode, I get the ERROR - "Cannot find control file 'springer.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?"
Also, If I compile it in pdfLaTeX mode, my references disappeared and question mark will be replaced in the text! what should I do?

Here is a part of my paper's text:

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[ singlelinecheck=false % <-- important ]{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools,extarrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document} 
...text...
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{MyCollection1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you get a question mark that suggests that you don't use `biblatex` (for which Biber would be the right backend), but standard BibTeX-bibliographies. In that case you need to run BibTeX and not Biber. But we can only be sure that this is the right solution if we get to see a full example document, please share an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) with us.

Comment: When I compile it in BibTeX mode, it works correctly. But, biber does not work and I get that error.

Comment: As I say without an MWE I can only speculate, but from what you told us so far I'm guessing that you use a way to create your bibliography that is *incompatible* with Biber. So whatever you do to Biber, it won't work, because your document is not set up to work with Biber. Why do you want to run Biber when BibTeX works? (BTW: If this document is for Springer (the publisher) it is really quite unlikely that you should be using Biber. Their templates usually use BibTeX.)

Comment: Yes, I want to submit the paper to the Springer information securityjournal, but when I attach the LaTeX form of the paper and next the paper is built to be approved in final step, my references disappeared! I don't know what to do. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, you will have to share more information with us. What does you document look like (**please post an MWE**)? When you write about the document being built does that refer to a local compilation on your machine or to remote compilation that happens on Springer's after you upload your paper? Are there any author guidelines for the journal? Did you read those guidelines? Do they mention how to submit bibliographies? ...

Comment: How can I share a part of my text with you?

Comment: Please edit a minimal working example (as explained in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) into your question.

Comment: I added a part of my paper into this question as an MWE.

Answer (score 6):

The MWE clearly shows that you use BibTeX-based bibliography solution (e.g. the `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`). In particular you do not use `biblatex`.

Biber can only be used as a bibliography backend with `biblatex`.

So the solution is not to run Biber, run BibTeX instead.

Comment: What should I do to use biblatex instead? I think the problem that I have is relating to the kind of compiling! Am I right?

Comment: @Jamshid Do not use `biblatex` with that document! You can't use `biblatex` with the document as shown. I have not done further research into Springer's author guidelines, but I would be very surprised if they were happy if you tried to use `biblatex`. Yes. Your main issue is with how to compile your document. Just compile your document with BibTeX instead of Biber. If you have an editor who does that for you, tell it to run BibTeX, not Biber. If you have set up your editor to use Biber instead of BibTeX, follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 in reverse.

Comment: When I use BibTeX only, no action takes place! I mean compiler does not do any things, no change in generated pdf. What should I do to compile it with BibTeX?

Comment: @Jamshid Run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX in that order. BibTeX can only work if there was a successful LaTeX run before and the changes can only propagate to the PDF if you run LaTeX again after BibTeX was run. If you are still having trouble after running that sequence check the `.log` and ´.blg` files for warnings and errors and fix them before you retry.

Comment: I compiled it in order what you said, pdflatex, Bibtex, pdflatex, and pdflatex. It works correctly and no problem. But, when I attach it to the journal submission process, does not work and the references disappear! I don't know what to do. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jamshid Well that is different. Sometimes journals need you to include the `.bbl` file into the `.tex` file, see hhttps://www.overleaf.com/help/219. But the exact workflow will depend on your journal, read the submission guidelines and any documentation they provide thoroughly. If all else fails contact the editor.